# Extract comma separated number from a string

Tags: regex

I want to extract the comma-separated number from below string using REGEX

```
String = "the Total Cost, being £10,000,000 at the date of this Agreement";
```

Output Expected: £10,000,000

I tried this:

```
\£[^]\w,\d*,\d*
```

But it's giving me an error in asp.net code: "Unterminated [] set".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: \£[^]\w,\d*,\d* - this works but is this the right way

Comment: What's wrong if it works?

Comment: Getting this error when running in asp.net code - Unterminated [] set.... Works fine on regexr

Comment: To you, what is `[^]` supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query `(£(?:[0-9]{1,3},?)+)`

`(` start capturing

`£` search a £

`(?:` starting a non capturing group

`[0-9]{1,3}` search from 1 to 3 digits

`,?` search from 0 or 1 comma

`)+` counting the non capturing group at least once

`)` stop capturing

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8MlKu2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```js
var str = "the Total Cost, being £10,000,000 at the date of this Agreement";
var regex = /£[\,\d]+/g;
var match = str.match(regex);
console.log(match);
```